# Phonegap - the best way to discover the country iso code from a user

Tags: cordova, iso

what is the best and fastest way to get the country iso code by
starting an App build with phonegap? There is a function to get the
geo coordinates, but not the Iso code. For getting the iso code maybe
it is necessary to call an external webservice and get the iso by
given coordinates. Is there a simplest way?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: If you know lat/lon coords ->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for where the user is at the moment or for something more like the users language/nationallity? For the latter you could always look at what's in `navigator.language`. Depending on target platform it'll give you either just language code ('en' on my Android test machine) or language code and country code ('en-us' on my iOS test machine). To see what it will give you, go with your device's stock browser [here](http://www.plexical.com/sandbox/micro-jsrepl.html) and type in `navigator.language` in the text input box.

Otherwise, casual browsing of [the HTML5 Geolocation spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#coordinates_interface) seems to indicate that you'll either need a web-service or package a datafile with codes in the app. [This](http://www.geonames.org/export/) seems to be a pretty good one.

Answer (score 1):

I found navigator.language sometimes only gave me the language and not the locale (eg "en" rather than "en-gb"). To solve this in android I created a new java class in src/com called DeviceCulture.java with this code:

```
package com;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DeviceCulture {

    public String get() {
        try{            
            return Locale.getDefault().toString();//get the locale from the Android Device      
        }catch(Exception e){
            return "";
        }   
    }
}
```

Then add this before the super.loadUrl line in /src/com/phonegap/YOUR_APP/App.java

```
DeviceCulture deviceCulture = new DeviceCulture();
appView.addJavascriptInterface(deviceCulture , "DeviceCulture");
```

Then in your javascript use this to get the locale (eg "en_GB")

```
window.DeviceCulture.get();
```

Comment: you mentioned "appView.addJavascriptInterface(deviceCulture , "DeviceCulture");" which has to be pasted before /src/com/phonegap/YOUR_APP/App.java. What is this appView ?