# Determine iOS "region format"

Tags: ios, html, cordova

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578347/phonegap-the-best-way-to-discover-the-country-iso-code-from-a-user) shows how to access the iOS Language setting using `navigator.language`, but how can I determine the User's "Region Setting"? The goal is to do this within a PhoneGap html5 application.

Language and Region Format are two distinct settings:

[image: Language and Region Format are two distinct settings]