# How can I find a user’s country using HTML5 geolocation?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm familiar with HTML5 geolocation for returning rough coordinates of the user’s location.

However, how can I return the name of the country that their coordinates are in?

Comment: Duplicate question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country

Comment: See perhaps the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude.

Comment: Geolocation is not part of HTML5: http://isgeolocationpartofhtml5.com/

Comment: Well this is awkward https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': <YOURLATLNGRESPONSEFROMGEO>}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    var loc = getCountry(results);
                }
            }
        });

    function getCountry(results)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++)
        {
        var shortname = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
        var longname = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        var type = results[0].address_components[i].types;
        if (type.indexOf("country") != -1)
        {
            if (!isNullOrWhitespace(shortname))
            {
                return shortname;
            }
            else
            {
                return longname;
            }
        }
    }

}

function isNullOrWhitespace(text) {
    if (text == null) {
        return true;
    }
    return text.replace(/\s/gi, '').length < 1;
}
```

This is what I use :)

Comment: This is almostt perfect, but google returns 'United Kingdom' rather than 'England' or 'Scotland' etc.. Ideally it needs to return 'England' etc as the purpose of the app I'm building is to identify between them two! :/

Comment: Look through the different types and see if you can grab what you want. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Comment: Just to be super picky here but it is safer to use '===' instead of '==' for comparing null values.

Comment: Just a heads up: "Geocoding Service: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"

Answer (score 38):

If you just want the country, here's a much simpler approach using [`ws.geonames.org`](http://ws.geonames.org) rather than Google:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        $.getJSON('http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode', {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
            type: 'JSON'
        }, function(result) {
            alert(result.countryName);
        });
    });
}​
```

Normally I would say that using a Google service would mean greater reliability, but with so many Google services being retired lately it's probably a good idea to look at some other solutions.

---

By the way, I did some experiments using all the free geocoding services I could find. It returns the country and the name of the service responsible as soon as one of them finds an acceptable result.

Feel free to play with it via JSFiddle: [Deferred look up country code via multiple geolocation webapis](http://jsfiddle.net/hippietrail/2H72s/)

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this answer ... and its the more open answer ;)

Comment: The best answer for countries that block Google :)

Comment: Error : lease add a username to each call in order for geonames to be able to identify the calling application and count the credits

Comment: @zloctb: Yes it seems geonames has changed its webservice to now require a registered username: "The parameter 'username' needs to be passed with each request. The username for your application can be registered [here](http://www.geonames.org/login). You will then receive an email with a confirmation link and after you have confirmed the email you can enable your account for the webservice on [your account page](http://www.geonames.org/manageaccount)"

Comment: Great solution. Just need to change http:// to https:// in each URL. ;)

Comment: ws.geonames.org now appears to be dead

Answer (score 2):

If you have problem getting geolocation to work like I had in Chrome, then I can recommend this alternative way (example with jQuery):

```
$.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
    const countryCode = data.country_code;
    const countryName = data.country_name;
    const ip = data.ip;
    const timezone = data.time_zone;
    const latitude = data.latitude;
    const longitude = data.longitude;

    alert("Country Code: " + countryCode);
    alert("Country Name: " + countryName);
    alert("IP: " + ip); 
    alert("Time Zone: " + timezone);
    alert("Latitude: " + latitude);
    alert("Longitude: " + longitude);   
});
```

Comment: neat solution with very few lines! also it doesn't require user interaction to find out his location.

Comment: Note as of 2020 this does not work. Service is now premium (though there is a limited free account).

Comment: It redirects to https://ipstack.com/, that has pricing.

Answer (score 1):

pay attention you need set 'username' property for using this api,otherwise you'll get error.

```
setTimeout(function() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                        $.getJSON('http://api.geonames.org/countryCode', {
                            lat : position.coords.latitude,
                            lng : position.coords.longitude,
                            type : 'JSON',
                            username : 'demo'
                        }, function(result) {
                            alert(result.countryName);
                        });
                    });
                }

            }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer as from @hippietrail but with another service without registration.

```
if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

  $.ajax('http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/coordinates2politics/'
    + position.coords.latitude + ','
    + position.coords.longitude, {dataType: 'jsonp'})
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if ( textStatus === 'success' ) {
      var country = data[0].politics[0].name
      alert(country)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using geoloc or IP lookup APIs (are free for dev use only)

Using `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` and file extracted from `moment-timezone`

Link to demo ([user region code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-azokeh?file=index.js)), you can download a file.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a [Reverse Geocoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding) service.