# Free JavaScript Plugin to get user location

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, geolocation

Is there any free API/Web Service where I can get geolocation of those who visit my HTTP secure website?

before I use `https://ssl.geoplugin.net/` to check this, but now they require a premium key to request location. I also tried to use the Google Maps GeoLocation API but it gives a wrong location. So I end up asking for any free javascript plugin to use. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a feature of HTML5, so to do this:

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else{
        x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

Sourced from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: You should paste the code here instead of just including links.

Comment: How can I get Country and Region with that?

Comment: @lexeRoy, for that you could use google maps. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747833/how-can-i-find-a-users-country-using-html5-geolocation).

Comment: This kind of answers the problem--but not really. There are two types of geolocation. Explicit (which is the example you provided) and implicit which tries to determine on its own where you are located (which is like the ssl.geoplugin site)