# Redirection By Location

Tags: jquery, html, meta-tags

I want to know if i could to implement some jQuery code or something in my code to redirect my website for people who are in my country and those who are not.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1;url=http://www.meuurl.net/br">
```

For example, people who access http://www.meuurl.net that are in my country will be redirected to http://www.meuurl.net/BR and others that are out will be redirected to http://www.meuurl.net/US.

That is possible catching by IP or something like that?
Thanks

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747833/how-can-i-find-a-users-country-using-html5-geolocation

Comment: But this link dont show how i do that

Comment: It tells you a possible way to get the location of your visitors.