# Get iso code using reverse lookup with google api

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I found some code in this post: [How can I get the country and region code using geolocation instead of full country and region names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703918/how-can-i-get-the-country-and-region-code-using-geolocation-instead-of-full-coun)

I want to get the users iso country code (2 digit).

But I cannot figure out why it doesn't work? In console on chrome I get ";uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; " on line 40

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M9kzT/

```
<script>
    var region = "";
    var country = "";
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
          {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,noGeolocation);
          } else {
              console.log('nope');
          }
    }
    function showPosition(position)
    {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlong}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  if (results[0]) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++)
                    {
                        var longname = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                        var type = results[0].address_components[i].types;
                        if (type.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") != -1)
                        {
                            region = longname;
                        }
                        if (type.indexOf("country") != -1)
                        {
                            country = short_name;
                        }
                      }
              }
        });
    }
  }
    function noGeolocation()
    {
        console.log('nope2');   
    }

    getLocation();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 `}` missplaced: one is missing one is not necessary:

```
    function showPosition(position) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlong}, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                        var longname = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                        var type = results[0].address_components[i].types;
                        if (type.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") != -1) {
                            region = longname;
                        }
                        if (type.indexOf("country") != -1) {
                            country = short_name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        });
    }

///}
```

**Update:** Changed function `showPosition()` to log long and short country name:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlong}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                    var longname = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                    var types = results[0].address_components[i].types;

                    for (var typeIdx = 0; typeIdx < types.length; typeIdx++) {
                        if (types[typeIdx] == 'country') {
                            console.log(results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
                            console.log(results[0].address_components[i].short_name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks.

I was kind of hoping this code would somehow give me some data to output, but I don't know how to do that. I thought the country = short_name would be simple to output via a console.log(country) but it doesn't show anything. How do i get this script to show me the country code via  console log for example?

Comment: For my place I got it as `results[0].address_components[3].short_name`. And you have to check for `types` 'country'.