# Google Maps address_components short_name ISO-Codes

Tags: google-maps

I want to parse the short_name of the google maps detail search for the country and want to know if this is the [iso-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) (iso 3166-1) or just an abbreviation from google? On the google pages i only find a description of the meaning of the field.

e. g.

```
, {
  "long_name": "United States",
  "short_name": "US",
  "types": [ "country", "political" ]
}
```

In the google docs i only found this:

> short_name is an abbreviated textual name for the address component, if available. For example, an address component for the state of Alaska may have a long_name of "Alaska" and a short_name of "AK" using the 2-letter postal abbreviation.

So the short name is also available for other parts for example states. 
But maybe someone used this also and can verify that the short_name of the country fits the ISO-Code standard. 
I just tested some countries and it fits so far.

Comment: Although assuming things is never good, the assumption that the ISO 3166-1 is the exact same thing as what Google is using is a strong assumption.

Comment: Have a look at similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703918/how-can-i-get-the-country-and-region-code-using-geolocation-instead-of-full-coun).