# Call javascript function based on region

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone tell me how to call one javascript function if page is loaded in India and call another javascript function if page is loaded in other country.

Comment: You'd need to use PHP to retrieve what coutry the visitor is in. Or is it possible in pure JS?

Comment: Use geolocation + google maps to retrieve the user country: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747833/how-can-i-find-a-user-s-country-using-html5-geolocation

Comment: https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/store-wide/get-a-visitors-location

Comment: A JS-only solution on modern browsers seems possible, Have a look at the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation). To convert lat/lng pairs  to country codes see [Google's ReverseGeocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) (You'll have to extract the relevant info from the json/xml delivered). See Fabrizio Calderan's linked SO answer

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to get Visitor region. This Code help You to find that. [Reffer](http://briancray.com/posts/find-web-visitors-location-javascript-google-api)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=API_KEY_GOES_HERE"></script>
```

Then main script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if(google.loader.ClientLocation)
    {
        visitor_lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
        visitor_lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
        visitor_city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
        visitor_region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
        visitor_country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
        visitor_countrycode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
        document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Lat/Lon: ' + visitor_lat + ' / ' + visitor_lon + '</p><p>Location: ' + visitor_city + ', ' + visitor_region + ', ' + visitor_country + ' (' + visitor_countrycode + ')</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Whoops!</p>';
    }
</script>
```

After this find your client  Region call the JavaScript to by region name.

1. store value of the country.
2. Call the JavaScript Functions Which you want call. [Reffer](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146003/accessing-a-function-from-other-js-file)