# How to throw popup only to those who are visiting from India?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show an entry popup only to those who are visiting from India using JavaScript.

Comment: You need to give more detail when asking questions and describe what you have already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747833/how-can-i-find-a-user-s-country-using-html5-geolocation (and numerous duplicates linked from there)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly get the IP of the visitor

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.ip);
    });
});
```

Then use a service that actually returns country names, like `FreeGeoIp`

```
$.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
    var country = data.country_name;
    var ip = data.ip;
});
```

After that shw your popup

```
if(country == 'India') {
    //......
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Munawir.

Comment: this works for me
$(window).load(function () {
                $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
                    var country = response.country;
                    //alert(country);
                    if (country == 'IN') {
                        $("#myModal").modal({
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            keyboard: false
                        });
                    }
                }, "jsonp");
            });

Answer (score -1):

You need to do IP Geo-location. There are a quite a few plugins that will help with this, find the one that best suits your application.