# Given longitude and latitude, how can I get the code and name of a country?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Given longitude and latitude, how can I get the code and name of a country?

From this [source](https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv) I have obtained the following data that correspond to the latitude and longitude of countries. How can I get the name and code of the country in which some coordinates are located?

```
[
  {
    "countryCode": "AD",
    "latitude": "42.546245",
    "longitude": "1.601554",
    "countryName": "Andorra"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "AE",
    "latitude": "23.424076",
    "longitude": "53.847818",
    "countryName": "United Arab Emirates"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "AF",
    "latitude": "33.93911",
    "longitude": "67.709953",
    "countryName": "Afghanistan"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "AG",
    "latitude": "17.060816",
    "longitude": "-61.796428",
    "countryName": "Antigua and Barbuda"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "AI",
    "latitude": "18.220554",
    "longitude": "-63.068615",
    "countryName": "Anguilla"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "AL",
    "latitude": "41.153332",
    "longitude": "20.168331",
    "countryName": "Albania"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "AM",
    "latitude": "40.069099",
    "longitude": "45.038189",
    "countryName": "Armenia"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "AN",
    "latitude": "12.226079",
    "longitude": "-69.060087",
    "countryName": "Netherlands Antilles"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "AO",
    "latitude": "-11.202692",
    "longitude": "17.873887",
    "countryName": "Angola"
  },
  ...
]
```

Full dataset https://jsfiddle.net/kmznxrhe/

For example, given the following coordinates Latitude: 12.4157952, Longitude: -86.8777984, how can I obtain the name and code of the country in which those coordinates are located?

I do not share an example because I do not really know how to do this task

Thanks in advance

Comment: This dataset doesn't really cover the area of the country, so unless you get that I don't see how you can find which country coordinates 12.4157952, -86.8777984 belong to.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude

Comment: This question appears to be duplicated. There are some possible answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747833/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find a user’s country using HTML5 geolocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747833/how-can-i-find-a-user-s-country-using-html5-geolocation)

Comment: I understand those are the latitude and longitude of the geometric center point for each Country and area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have obtained the following data that correspond to the latitude and longitude of countries.

So your dataset contains only a *single* coordinate that is inside the country, without giving any information about the borderline of said country.

> How can I obtain the name and code of the country in which those coordinates are located?

This process is called reverse geocoding. There are some APIs available for this task, e.g. OSM's [Nominatim API](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Reverse/).

An example URL querying the coordinates you gave as an example:
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=12.4157952&lon=-86.8777984&zoom=3&format=json

Answer (score 1):

With this dataset the only thing that you can do is get the country by a **specific latitude and longitude**

```js
const data = [
  {
    "countryCode": "country",
    "latitude": "latitude",
    "longitude": "longitude",
    "countryName": "name"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "NR",
    "latitude": "-0.522778",
    "longitude": "166.931503",
    "countryName": "Nauru"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "ZW",
    "latitude": "-19.015438",
    "longitude": "29.154857",
    "countryName": "Zimbabwe"
  }
]

let myCountry = data.find(country => country.latitude === "-19.015438" && country.longitude === "29.154857")

console.log(myCountry)

//output
//{
//  "countryCode": "ZW",
//  "latitude": "-19.015438",
//  "longitude": "29.154857",
//  "countryName": "Zimbabwe"
//}
```

But you can't check the coverage (for the example: 12.4157952, -86.8777984), to do that I recommend [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude)