# How to get the official language from latitude and longitude

Tags: blackberry, java-me, gps

I want to get the official language for a location, defined by latitude and longitude.
I am using the Blackberry platform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/working-with-latitude-longitude-values-in-java

Comment: @Mob, how does that answer the question?

Comment: @GETah I did not answer the question. It's a comment. I posted that just to give him a few pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is to get [the country you are in based on Lat Lon](http://www.maxmind.com/app/country_latlon) and then find the [official language in that part of the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_official_languages).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're limited to offline processing you can call one of the services mentioned in
"[Get country from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude)"

and then iterate through Logale.getAvailableLocales() to get the language