# Getting country code

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-market-filtering, mobile-country-code

I am implementing In App Purchase.In the in app product list,I have configured few products for country A and few products for country B. So my application should show only those products configured for country A for a user in country A and similarly for user in country B.
So when my app communicates with my content server, the app should be able to send the device country with server requests. How can I achieve this?

I have used TelephonyManager : getNetworkCountryIso () method to get the Mobile Country Code(MCC). But the documentation says "Only when user is registered to a network. Result may be unreliable on CDMA networks"
Also, when i tried this,

1. on Samsung devices(2.3) with wifi internet, no sim, i got the code
2. on samsung device(2.3) with sim,no internet connectivity, i got the code
3. on lg (2.2) with wifi, no sim i got the code
4. xperia x10 (2.1)  with wifi internet,no sim .. i did not get the code
5. xperia x10 (2.3) with sim,with internet conncetion.. i got the code

All where gsm. I can't figure out why i couldn't get the mcc for 4th case?

Also, how does google identify the country of the device for filtering applications in market?

Any idea?

Edit: I tried in Dell Venue (2.2) with wifi, without sim: i did not get the MCC

Comment: Have you tried other Eclair(2.1) phones?

Comment: No. But I feel it is not OS dependent. I could not get the MCC in Dell Venue with 2.2 with no SIM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think google checks for either [getSimCountryIso](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso%28%29). This is usually reliable. But i maybe wrong

Comment: this again is available with SIM. What if i have data connectivity through WiFi. But no sim?

Comment: you could get the last know location of user using LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation and then get the country by either using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-values-in-google-map-android