# What to find out locale using GPS co-ordinates(Longitude,latitude)?

Tags: java

I have GPS co-ordinate and i want find the Locale using those co-ordinates.
I have option to use Google Map api but i am looking for any other option to get the location details so that i could find out locale.

Please guide me how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Open Street Map reverse geocode API:

> http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

Ore are you looking for other data than location information? Like timezone, spoken language, used currency, etc.? For that you would use the locale data and mesh it up with other services.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps. First get the country code using the website described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude) and then try to convert the country code to locale - should be easy from here.