# How to use GeoNames Web Services using PHP

Tags: php, html, json, geolocation, geonames

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude?lq=1) and it looks very promising. However, the answer does not go in detail with regards the implementation.

**Basically, given the latitude and longitude, how can I use the [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) Web Service to get the country. I would like the returned result to be stored in a variable so that I can then continue working with it as I wish.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use javascript for that? Geonames doesn't seem to offer a javascript api for doing your exact query (see here: http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html). And remote file fetching via javascript is not a joy.

If you could use php for that, it would be as easy as

```
$country = file_get_contents("http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=49.03&lng=10.2");
```